# Is there a way to load a pyautogui screenshot into a PIL image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

Is there a way to load a pyautogui screenshot into PIL for further use? Please see code:

```
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()

pil_img = PIL.Image(???).load()
```

I have searched for an answer to this question, to no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pyautogui.screenshot()` function automatically returns a PIL `Image` object if you do not pass a filename argument to it, as per [the documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-screenshot-function).